# json - Taking value from response object, and inserting it in request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

> After the file has been successfully uploaded, the 'uploadSuccess' callback event gets triggered, and it receives an object describing the newly created media.
>
> One of the values in that object called 'hashed_id' is exactly what I need to insert into a PUT request.
>
> So I wrote the following script, but the Upload button doesn't even show up any more!

EDIT: The doc page for the upload widget provided code with curly quotes instead of straight quotes, causing the issue. Thanks for pointing that out, Tomalak.

```
    <div id="wistia-upload-widget" style="width: 350px; height: 50px;"></div>
    <script src="http://static.wistia.com/javascripts/upload_widget.js"></script>
    <script>
        var cback = function(response) {
console.log(response);
response.hashed_id
$.put(“https://api.wistia.com/v1/medias/” + response.hashed_id + “.json?name=NEW-NAME-HERE”)
}
        var widget1 = new wistia.UploadWidget({
divId: 'wistia-upload-widget',
publicProjectId: 'blahblahprojectid',
uploadSuccess: cback,
buttonText: 'Upload Video'
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My crystal ball tells me that you have copied source code from some blog that apparently replaces straight quotes (`"`) with curly quotes (`“`, `”`).

You have pasted that code into your page without carefully proof-reading it and without checking the JS console for errors. Don't do that.

Here is how your attempt would look like:

```
var widget1 = new wistia.UploadWidget({
    divId: 'wistia-upload-widget',
    publicProjectId: 'blahblahprojectid',
    uploadSuccess: function (response) {
        $.put("https://api.wistia.com/v1/medias/" + response.hashed_id + ".json", {
            name: "NEW-NAME-HERE" // probably sth. like $("#someInput").val()
        }).done(function () {
            console.log("rename successful");
        }).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
            console.log("rename failed: " + error);
        });
    },
    buttonText: 'Upload Lesson Video'
});
```